# Javascript Uncaught TypeError : Object has no method

Tags: javascript

in my javascript application I am getting the following error upon page load.

```
Uncaught TypeError : Object #<Object> has no method 'showHideCleanupButton'
```

this appears (inside Chrome's debugger) to be blowing up inside the method 'getAllItemsForDisplay'where it calls 'this.showHideCleanupButton'

here is a link to it on jsFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/cpeele00/4fVys/

Any help would be greatly appreciated :-)

Thanks,

Chris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that this is the relevant piece of code:

```
    getAllItemsForDisplay: function() {
        $.getJSON('services/act_getAllItems/', function(data) {
            $('#items-list').empty();
            $('#items-listTmpl').tmpl(data).appendTo('#items-list');

            this.showHideCleanupButton();
            BeefyUtils.noSelect();
        });
    },
```

What are you expecting `this` to be set to inside the `getJSON` callback?  Have you set a breakpoint on the relevant statement and looked at what the value of `this` is?

If I understand the jQuery doc correct, by default `this` inside a getJSON call will be a reference to the ajax options that were originally passed in.  I think it's possible to change what `this` will be with ajaxSetup, but I don't see that you've done that.

If you want to refer to the `this` at the beginning of `getAllItemsForDisplay`, then you need to save that into another variable that you can use like this:

```
    getAllItemsForDisplay: function() {
        var obj = this;
        $.getJSON('services/act_getAllItems/', function(data) {
            $('#items-list').empty();
            $('#items-listTmpl').tmpl(data).appendTo('#items-list');

            obj.showHideCleanupButton();
            BeefyUtils.noSelect();
        });
    },
```

Comment: In this context, this will be the context of the jQuery function that called the callback (or possibly the xhr object).

Comment: @tjameson - the doc for ajaxSetup seems to indicate that `this` will be set to point to the options object unless set differently in the options object.  I don't have a testable example to look at it myself, but that's what I can glean from the jQuery doc.

Comment: In either case, it's probably not what the OP was expecting.

Comment: @jfriend00, thanks for the answer, it worked! thanks to everyone else who responded as well!

Answer (score 1):

To piggy-back on jfriend00's answer, change this:

```
getAllItemsForDisplay: function() {
    $.getJSON('services/act_getAllItems/', function(data) {
        $('#items-list').empty();
        $('#items-listTmpl').tmpl(data).appendTo('#items-list');

        this.showHideCleanupButton();
        BeefyUtils.noSelect();
    });
},
```

to this:

```
getAllItemsForDisplay: function() {
    var self = this;
    $.getJSON('services/act_getAllItems/', function(data) {
        $('#items-list').empty();
        $('#items-listTmpl').tmpl(data).appendTo('#items-list');

        self.showHideCleanupButton();
        BeefyUtils.noSelect();
    });
},
```

This will give you the context that called getAllItemsForDisplay, which I assume is what you want.